# How to I countdown 270 to 0 within 5 seconds and also store their results or log to console

Tags: javascript, dom

How I write a code that counts down 270 to 0 within 5 seconds. I need it to set a value of `stroke-dashoffset` to update a progress bar animation.

Here is what I have tried but it is not working

```
 setInterval(function(){
  let countdown = 270;
countdown = --countdown <= 0 ? 270 : countdown;

// It only logs 269. I want it to run down from 270 to 0 and update the value for the stroke-dashoffset
console.log(countdown);

// Fill up the progress bar using the strokedashoffset property
circProgress.style.strokeDashoffset = countdown;
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of loop/interval that runs `--countdown`? The code you posted will only do `--countdown` once, so you'll never get to 0...

Comment: @TimLewis The countdown is in a function and it runs with setInterval of 5000. This is just a snippet

Comment: You should edit your question to provide that, so we don't have to guess at what you already have :) Additionally, is `let countdown = 270;` outside of that interval?

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you. I have done that now

Comment: Thanks! So yeah, if `let countdown = 270;` is _inside_ the `setInterval()`, each time it runs, your counter will be reset to `270`. You need to move that outside of the function :)

Comment: So I tried it and it didn't quite work well. It wasn't in sync with the other animation sequence that also ran at 5 seconds interval. The 270 to 0 is used to fill up the progress bar for each animation sequence that runs at 5 seconds

Comment: Yeah, I doubt that was a complete fix, but it was definitely an issue :). Are you able to make a JSFiddle of this? It's a little difficult to picture what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

By define a setInterval, like this:

```js
let countdown = 270;
let seconds = 5000; //5 seconds


setInterval(() => {

  countdown = --countdown <= 0 ? 270 : countdown;
  console.log(countdown);
  
}, seconds/countdown)
```

Comment: How do I make this work with an animation that runs every five seconds with a setInterval already. I tried this but it didn't work well. The values of this ran too fast and wasn't in sync with the 5 seconds of each animation sequence

Comment: @Idris if run too fast, increase the seconds time or even not split seconds in countdown.